# EF Core - Count from a specific column

Tags: ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1

I **almost** have my EF Core query working... This is the SQL getting produced (notice the Count(*):

```
SELECT [u].[Key], [u].[Url], [u].[CreatedBy], [u].[CreatedOn], COUNT(*) AS [Clicks]
FROM [URLs] AS [u]
LEFT JOIN [OwnerUrls] AS [o] ON [u].[Key] = [o].[ShortUrlKey]
LEFT JOIN [Clicks] AS [c] ON [u].[Key] = [c].[ShortUrlKey]
GROUP BY [u].[Key], [u].[Url], [u].[CreatedBy], [u].[CreatedOn]
```

What I *need* is (have Count look at a specific column/table)

```
SELECT [u].[Key], [u].[Url], [u].[CreatedBy], [u].[CreatedOn], COUNT(c.ID) AS [Clicks]
FROM [URLs] AS [u]
LEFT JOIN [OwnerUrls] AS [o] ON [u].[Key] = [o].[ShortUrlKey]
LEFT JOIN [Clicks] AS [c] ON [u].[Key] = [c].[ShortUrlKey]
GROUP BY [u].[Key], [u].[Url], [u].[CreatedBy], [u].[CreatedOn]
```

Here is the EF Query that I'm using...

```
            query = (from u in db.URLs
                         join ou in db.OwnerUrls on u.Key equals ou.ShortUrlKey into urlOwners
                         from subSet in urlOwners.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join c in db.Clicks on u.Key equals c.ShortUrlKey into urlClicks
                         from subClicks in urlClicks.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         group subClicks by new { u.Key, u.Url, u.CreatedBy, u.CreatedOn } into g
                         select new ShortURL()
                         {
                             Key = g.Key.Key,
                             Url = g.Key.Url,
                             CreatedBy = g.Key.CreatedBy,
                             CreatedOn = g.Key.CreatedOn,
                             Clicks = g.Count()
                         });
```

I've tried changing the g.Count() to g.Select(x=>x.Id).Count() and that just causes EF Core to barf and complain about client side evaluation vs server side evaluation etc..

I should mention that the reason I'm joining the first model (OwnerUrls) is to support a where clause that I didn't include here...

Thanks!

Comment: did you solve it in the end? I have similar issue and cannot find anything anywhere.. so WEIRD!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a EF developer, but have worked with SQL Server for a while now. In SQL Server i would use COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID) to eliminate any duplicates you might get from JOINS.

If duplicates are impossible due to the model the COUNT(*) shoud be sufficient.

Maybe this might help:
https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/51892585/linq-select-distinct-count-performed-in-memory

Comment: Thanks for the answer Patrik - because c.ID is from a join (Clicks) it is already distinct, but it's a left join so Count(c.ID)  - or anything from the c table is needed, otherwise Count(*) will always return a 1, and will never return a 0 - by counting based on a LeftJoin relationship I can return a 0 when there are no corresponding records.